# How to bind a service to multiple activities without it being stopped while navigating between activities?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I was wondering, in Android, I have a service that holds a timer since connecting to a BLE device.  I would like the service to stay bound until either the device disconnects or until the entire app is closed.  I **do not** want the service to be stopped while navigating between activities.

Here is my Service code:

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "TimerService";
    private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    Handler onlineTimeHandler;
    long startTime = 0L, timeInMilliseconds = 0L, timeSwapBuff = 0L, updatedTime = 0L;
    int mins, secs, hours;
    String time = "";
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("TimerHandler");

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onCreate");

        mHandlerThread.start();
        onlineTimeHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        onlineTimeHandler.post(updateTimerThread);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onBind");
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onRebind");
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onUnbind");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onDestroy");
        if(onlineTimeHandler!=null){
            onlineTimeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        }
        if (mHandlerThread != null) {
            mHandlerThread.quit();
        }
    }


    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        TimerService getService() {
            return TimerService.this;
        }
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            mins = secs / 60;

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("android.intent.action.TICK");

            sendBroadcast(intent);

            if (secs % 60 == 0) {
                intent.putExtra("minutes", mins);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            onlineTimeHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

I tried having an abstract `BaseActivity` class implement `ServiceConnection`, but it appears the service still gets stopped while navigating between activities.  Could it be because the BaseActivity's `onDestroy` method gets called each time I navigate between activities?  I would like it to stay bound unless the app is destroyed or if the device disconnects.

Comment: Start and Stop the service form the MyApplication class, that extends application.it's has application scope.
Your Service is being stopped due to onDestory is called every time, when change activity
OR Try using BusEvent , that will help in communication easily

Comment: But how would the service be stopped when the app closes?

Comment: One application is killed, service will get destroyed

Comment: Please add all code that calls `bindService()/unbindService()`.